# Send Abstract Classes via the API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am currently trying to send something like this via. Cloud Endpoints:

```
public abstract class Transaction {
//...
}

public class BuyTransaction extends Transaction {
//...
}

public class UpgradeTransaction extends Transaction {
//...
}
```

My API-Method for that is something like

```
@ApiMethod(...)
public List<Transaction> getTransactions(User user) { /*...*/}
```

But the generated Endpoint-Libs only contain a Transaction-model but ignore the other classes. When i try this:

```
List<? extends Transactions>
```

The endpoint-lib-generation fails entirely and says that it's not supported. Is there any other way to send different classes that inherit from abstract classes over the wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. The general problem you are trying to solve doesn't always have a viable solution, as you'd need to combine all the properties of `Transaction` and any extending classes. Consider these classes:

```
public abstract class Foo {
  //...
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
  public String prop;

  // getters and setters
}

public class Baz extends Foo {
  public Integer prop;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Should the conglomeration of classes represented on the client side by `Foo` contain a `prop` field that is a `String` or an `Integer`?

If you want to allow anything extending `Foo` be sent over the wire, you must provide all the properties you want sent as part of `Foo`.

Comment: Well you could use reflection to retrieve the properties and the class name and later reassemble it back together at client/server side. But it seems like this isn't a feature included in google-cloud-endpoints.